# How to create a Custom TaskPane in VSTO Excel?

Tags: .net, vsto

I have been looking into a few Excel Addin applications in which a task pane called ADXTaskpane is created using https://www.add-in-express.com. Can someone please help me in creating similar task pane with .Net code.

I used the basic code to create CustomTaskPane but there are few issues with this

1. I cannot change the Title once a CustomTaskPane is loaded. I have to remove and add another
2. When I use WPF or Windows User control to load into customtaskpane, it flickers (its a known issue)
3. Cannot minimize

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, sometimes it is far a lot easier to purchase the existing functionality if it suits your needs fully. Spending much time without any definitive output is not really a good idea. Moreover, the toolset brings other valuable benefits to developers.

1. You may create your own header on the task leaving the built-in name as blank.
2. It is not clear where and when it flickers. Anyway, you may try to use the `SuspendLayout` and [ResumeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout) to reduce flickerings when the form is created and populated with controls.
3. To create the minimized state you just change control's layout and change the size of the custom task pane. I.e. to minimize the task pane you need to reduce the width or height (for horizontal layouts).

P.S. Don't forget to say `Hello from Eugene` if you decide to switch to using Add-in Express.